# Tracing what references a buffer in memory using Olly?

Tags: ollydbg, memory, tracing

im wondering if anyone knows how i would go about finding references to a buffer in memory, the scenario is that i have found the buffer that the program receives from a server, the buffer is encoded so im trying to find the routine that is going to decode it, i know its possible since people have done it in the past and im just trying to re-create it to learn.

Anyways so i tried placing a hardware breakpoint on the buffer but it only gets hit like 3-4 times and none of them really copy the buffer or modify it in any way :/ so im wondering if im not finding all references to the buffer ? and how one would go about this in general.